# Ajax with Symfony3

Tags: ajax, twig, symfony

I want to display a list of users dynamically but it doesn't work. I tested the query by itself and it works just fine yet it still doesn't show anything. This is the script

```
 <script>
    function showUser() {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("user-list-div").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","{{ path('ajax_update')}}",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
</script>
```

This is the controller action:

```
 public function searchUsersAction(Request $request)
{
    /*$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $request = $this->get('request');*/
    $projectName = $request->get('projectName');
    echo($projectName);
    //$projectId=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SocialProMeetingBundle:meetingUser')->findName($projectName);
    //echo(count($projectId));
    //foreach($projectId as $pId) {
        //$projectId->getPId();
        $pus = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SocialProMeetingBundle:meetingUser')->findProjectUsers($projectName);
    //}
    $response = "<select class=\"select2_multiple form-control\" multiple=\"multiple\">";
    foreach($pus as $user){
        $response . "<option>" . $user . "</option>";
    }
    $response = $response."</select> ";
    return new Response($response);
    //return($pus);
    //call repository function
}
```

and this is the query

```
public function findProjectUsers($projectName){
    $query=$this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            "SELECT u.firstName FROM SocialProDefaultBundle:User u, SocialProProjectBundle:Project p, SocialProProjectBundle:ProjectUser pu WHERE u.id = pu.user AND p.id=pu.project AND p.name='$projectName'");
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Check your Apache/Nginx/PHP logs for errors please.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. I'm working with phpMyAdmin on wamp server. I tested the query and it returned the correct result @michail_w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is incorrect. You need to concatenate the $projectName like so:

```
public function findProjectUsers($projectName){
    $query=$this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            "SELECT u.firstName
                FROM SocialProDefaultBundle:User u,
                SocialProProjectBundle:Project p,
                SocialProProjectBundle:ProjectUser pu
                WHERE u.id = pu.user AND p.id=pu.project AND p.name=:name"
        )->setParameter('name', $projectName);
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

I'm not sure if that will fix everything, but at least it will get the query working properly.

Comment: Keeping the SQL injection is quite a bad idea.

Comment: What do you mean @AlainTiemblo? Can you add more details?

Comment: Sure. `AND p.name='".$projectName."'"`. What if I inject `' OR 1 --`

Comment: Hi there @AlainTiemblo. I can't provide a better answer since I now see there are a number of problems with the OPs code. I see your point about the SQL injection though. For the OPs reference, in your `searchUsersAction` you call `$request->get('projectName')`, but it would be better to pass the `SocialProProjectBundle:Project` id value as a parameter into your route, then query in Doctrine for your Project. Then pass that as a parameter to the query. Also you should do all this in your `searchUsersAction` code instead of having a separate function. But I think you will learn by experience.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear your problem, but see upstairs friend said there was a problem in your query, so I'm thinking, you can put the controller, the query do breakpoint debugging. Then the error precision lock down position. I the train of thought to solve the problem is so commonly.